# Logstash JSON code and Ruby not handling the decimal (float) properly

Tags: ruby, logstash, elastic-stack

I have Kafak <> Logstash (then Ruby) <> Elastic

Kafak Input:

```
{"customerid":"smit","last_name":"shah","age":10,"height":10,"weight":100,"automated_email":false, "header": { "endpoint":"/pay"}, "transaction": { "amount":100.50, "currency" : "SGD"}}
```

Logstash:

```
 json {
        source => "message"
      }

 mutate {
        convert => { "amount" => "float" }
    }
    ruby {
        # Cancel 90% of events
        path => "/usr/local/etc/logstash/main.rb"
        script_params => { "percentage" => 0.9 }
      }
    }
```

Ruby

```
transaction = event.get('transaction')
        puts transaction
        puts transaction['amount']
```

This prints:

```
{"amount"=>0.1005e3, "currency"=>"SGD"}
0.1005e3
```

Why I am not getting 100.5?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `transaction['amount'].to_f`

Comment: Nope It is still coming as `0.1005e3`